# WooCommerce Change Order Status without Sending Email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Signifyd with my website and when an order is submitted and paid for, the status is changed to held immediately and only when Signified notifies our webhook does it change to processing or refunded based on fraud.

Question: Right now the order becomes "Processing" which fires an email to the customer. Immediately after, my code sets it to Held and sends data to Signifyd. In a few seconds, Signifyd will either change it to Processing or Refunded. How do I prevent the second "Your order is Processing" email?

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order->update_status('on-hold');
```

Perhaps there is a way to set WooCommerce to have the initial order status something else instead so it goes from `Custom Status` -> `On Hold` -> `Processing (or) Refunded`

Comment: Well, you could go into the backend woocommerce > settings > emails and turn off the processing notification or change the template. Beyond that, you'll probably want to use a hook... https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Comment: As your question is not enough detailed related to the webhook that is used and about Signifyd changes that you can make, it's possible not  to guess things and give a useful answer. You should better directly ask Signifyd support.